# Calculate the class limits from the kernel density depending on the percentage of the source dataset

Tags: classification, arcgis-10.6, kernel-density

My goal is to make the class boundary of a kernel density dependent on a percentage of the input points.
Specifically I calculate the kernel density from 3000 points in a 50m x 50 m grid with a search radius of 16000 m in an area of about 357386 km². Now I want to divide the density result raster into two classes.  One class should contain 75% of the original points and the other class with the highest density values should contain 25% of the original points. So I want to set the threshold value for a density to a percentage of the original data.
Unfortunately, I have not yet found a way to make the class boundary dependent on the percentage of the original data points. Is this even possible?
I would be very happy about support. I work with ArcGIS 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:
-   Multipart To Singlepart
-   Multipoint feature class to single point
-   Kernel density
-   extract multi values to points
-   Sort table of input points with density values in ascending order and read off threshold value;